# cannot create buttons on layout views xcode storyboard set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

I have tried to create the buttons with custom image center on screen but to on avail. SO i resort to creating buttons programmatically to the main self.view. When it comes to execution , the buttons cannot be added.

The below is my code. PLease view

```
 UIButton *buttonA = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 88, 30)];
    [buttonA setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rc_logo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItemB = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonA];
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItemB;
    [navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];


    UIImage * ssssImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_back.png"] ;
    UIButton * btnPair ;
    [self setPosition : btnPair  image: ssssImage  positionAt: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 -  ssssImage.size.width/2,
                                                                          self.view.frame.size.height * 0.18 ,
                                                                          ssssImage.size.width/2,  ssssImage.size.height/2)];

    [self.scrollContain addSubview:btnPair];
}


-(void) setPosition  : (UIButton * ) btn image :  (UIImage * ) deviceImage  positionAt : (CGRect) frame   {


    btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    [btn setImage:deviceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    [btn setFrame: frame];

    btn.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    btn.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give it background color for debug process and check by placing breakpoints and watch frame and hidden property of button you are creating ...

And please specify which button not adding UIBarButton or UIButton ?

Comment: UIButtons , not UIBarBUttons